# jenkins send folder to other server through publish over ssh

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have setup jenkins and ssh and connection of ssh is fine I have test it. But When I try to send folder its not sending. My folder is in root means in workspace path is `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mydevproject`

Now I have added source files but I am not sure it will upload my folder or not also I have tried zip file as weel but its not uploading. I have tested ssh server when I was adding and its connecting fine but I am not getting it what's the issue in this to upload folder or file.

[image]

In build console its showing 0 transfer

```
SSH: Connecting from host [ip-172-myip25-38.us-east-2.compute.internal]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [nodeapptest] ...
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [nodeapptest] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Finished: SUCCESS
```